# Resque cannot load module - no such file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, load, require, resque

I am doing `resque` in Rails. In the Rails project, I have a file name `setup.rb` and `helper.rb` in the same directory. In `setup.rb` I have

```
require './helper'
```

When I tried to run `bundle exec rake resque:work QUEUE="*"` or `rake resque:work QUEUE="*"` I got error. The error is:

```
No such file to load -- ./helper
```

When I tried to rails console, `Dir.chdir` to that directory and type in `require './helper'` it return true, which means it works fine. I cannot explain why the `setup.rb` cannot require './helper'.

Answer (score 1):

try using Rails.root for the file path and make it absolute instead of relative

Comment: This does not work although I tried require '#{Rails.root}/app/workers/helper'.

Any idea ?

Comment: you have to use double quotes if you want to use the #{} replacement inside strings, require "#{Rails.root}/app/workers/helper", try also adding ".rd", require "#{Rails.root}/app/workers/helper.rd"